# Australian visa application stuck for 2 months

Tags: visas, us-citizens, australia, application-status

My son and wife applied for visitor visas to Australia in June, but while she got hers in two days, he is still waiting eight weeks later. They had to cancel their trip and they lost the money they spent on the expenses.

We are wondering if this is because he has high security clearance in the military, or if it is just a long process for some people? They want to go again in three months before their airline tickets expire, but the embassy could not help.

His application says "received", but we don't know what that means. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: what are your son's and his wife's nationalities? US citizens [usually do not need a visa to visit Australia](https://usa.embassy.gov.au/visa-faqs) and are eligible for [an Australian ETA](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601), which is [usually processed immediately, or within 12 hours](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601#HowTo).

Comment: They are both US and we were surprised  too.    Apparently it is a new rule since Australia re opened.  The sad part is he actually has dual citizenship with a  NZ passport which would have made it so easy  but has to travel  with US passport because he is  active military.  They only want to travel 2 weeks.

Comment: TIL that at least in the USAF use of a foreign passport requires permission. I presume asking for this permission would be even more complicated in practice?https://afrotc.asu.edu/sites/default/files/dual_citizenship_memo.pdf